# How to build a rest service accepting any request?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I want to test my integrated services. Therefore I need a rest-service, that takes any request to any url and responds with HTTP 200 - OK. (Later on the answer shall be configurable, based on the url.)

How can I build such a service with spring-boot?

---

I tried using a custom `HandlerInterceptor`, but this will only work, if the url is exposed:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new AllAccessInterceptor());
  }

  private static class AllAccessInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle() {
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      return true;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: See if you can use it as a reference point... https://github.com/gupta1vipin/springboot-productmatcher/tree/master/products-matcher

Comment: So do you want to pass an integrated service URL and HTTP method as a request parameter to a test rest service?

Comment: That is not, what I wanted. This project only exposes 2 endpoints. I want to be able to GET, POST and PATCH against any endpoint I can think of without needing to implement the endpoint.

Comment: @sadia Not exactly. I want to spin up my acceptor-service locally. Than configure it as remote service for a service I want to dev-test manually on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the spring boot in a whole and spring mvc in particular are not intended to do this in a nutshell, so any solution won't be straightforward and good in general.

So, yes, the interceptors technically can be a solution but then, how will you configure the actual answer (besides the 200 status there should be some data sent back to the caller part). What is the request to be checked is a post request and you expect to check a body of a very specific form.

Based on your comment

> I want to spin up my acceptor-service locally. Than configure it as remote service for a service I want to dev-test manually on my machine.

Consider using [Wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) as a mock server. It would work pretty much like mockito: 
You'll be able to specify the expectations like "if I call the remote service with the following params -> return that answer" and so forth. Technically it answers your question because you indeed won't need to implement the enpoint for each expectation specification that's exactly what wiremock does.

You can even run it with test containers in docker during the test so that it will start up at the beginning of the test and stop when the test is over but its a different topic.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.

Instead of returning `true` in the `preHandle` method, I need to return `false`. This will not allow any further execution of `Interceptors`.